# Counting the total number of characters in an std::set<std::string>

Tags: c++

I have a `std::set<std::string>` and I need to know the total number of characters (sum of all strings length):

```
static size_t SumLength(size_t value, const std::string &str)
{
    return str.length() + value;
}

size_t TotalLength(std::set<std::string> &stringSet)
{
   return std::accumulate(stringSet.begin(), stringSet.end(), 0, SumLength);
}
```

What do you think of this approach?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should make the parameter to `TotalLength` const, so you can use it on constant sets. Since `TotalLength` does not modify its argument, there is no reason not to use a const reference.

Also this is a small thing, but I'd change the name of `SumLength` to `AddLength` as `Sum` to me suggests that it operates on multiple strings.

Other than that your code looks perfectly fine and straight forward.

Comment: Good catch about the const and nice comment about the function name. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to improve the locality of reference of the code you might replace SumLength with a lambda function. This would prevent future maintainers/etc from putting lots of code between SumLength and TotalLength. The drawback would be that you'd lose the ability to call SumLength by another function outside of TotalLength.

Comment: Thanks, but no lambda on the current compiler that I have to use :(.